# IPv6 connection dropping on Debian 7

Tags: debian, ipv6

**EDIT**: I've tried something different based on searching around. This is now my `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# This line makes sure the interface will be brought up during boot
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0

# The primary network interface
iface eth0 inet static
    address 85.17.141.27
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 85.17.141.254
    # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
    dns-nameservers 85.17.150.123 85.17.96.69 85.17.150.123 62.212.64.122
    dns-search localdomain
    # up commands
    up ip addr add 85.17.141.33/24 dev eth0
    up ip -6 addr add 2001:1af8:4100:a00e:4::1/64 dev eth0
    up ip -6 ro add default via 2001:1af8:4100:a00e::1 dev eth0
```

Then `ip addr show eth0` outputs:

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
link/ether d4:ae:52:c5:d2:1b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 85.17.141.27/24 brd 85.17.141.255 scope global eth0
inet 85.17.141.33/24 scope global secondary eth0
inet6 2001:1af8:4100:a00e:d6ae:52ff:fec5:d21b/64 scope global dynamic 
   valid_lft 2591870sec preferred_lft 604670sec
inet6 2001:1af8:4100:a00e:4::1/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::d6ae:52ff:fec5:d21b/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

further `ip -6 ro` outputs:

```
2001:1af8:4100:a00e::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256 
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256 
default via 2001:1af8:4100:a00e::1 dev eth0  metric 1024 
default via fe80::2d0:ff:fe9e:1800 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 1024  expires 1627sec
default via fe80::2d0:2ff:fe33:3c00 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 1024  expires 1627sec
```

Eventually the two default proto kernel routes disappear from the output. My IPv6 connection still dropped at some point over night though. Again, simply running `sudo service networking stop && sudo service networking start` got everything working again. Those two `fe80` routes reappeared as well, not surprising. Anyone any ideas?

*aside*: at no point has any IPv4 connectivity had issues.

Comment: I am confused.  You claim it works, but you interfaces, has a `/64` mask, but the obfuscated ipv6 address has a `/128` mask.  Something isn't right there.

Comment: Your config still doesn't match your output. The config says `2001:1AF8:4100:A00E:4::1/64`, but the output says `2001:1AF8:4100:A00E:4::1/128`. Your config looks fine (I have lots of systems with very similar config) but you are doing something you are not telling us here...

Comment: I think the last edit has the connectivity issue fixed. I'm just now confused about the `scope global dynamic` address and where its come from.

Answer (score 1):

Scope global dynamic is coming  from [interface autoconfiguration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Modified_EUI-64). First half of it is the same your IPv6 prefix, and second half is EUI-64 (derived from 'FF:FE' and your ethernet MAC address, unless you are using [IPv6 privacy extensions](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4941))

If you don't want them, you can disable them by doing `sysctl net.ipv6.conf.eth.autoconf = 0` **BEFORE** bringing your interface up.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to configure IPv6 in Debian's `/etc/network/interfaces` file is:

```
iface eth0 inet6 static
        address 2001:1af8:4100:a00e:4::1
        netmask 64
        gateway 2001:1af8:4100:a00e::1
```

You should not have any of those extra `up` statements to configure your IPv6 address.